# RecyclerViewAdapter - list is being updated, but view is not

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, android-tv

I've made an app for Android TV which displays list of items from Firebase.

**Expected behaviour:**
When any change to database is done, fetch database and update the view.

**What's wrong?**
Data is fetched and displayed correctly, up to the moment I lock device. Afterwards it immediately stops refreshing view **only**. I put some "Log.d" in my adapter class to print updated list, and list is updated as it should be. So, in conclusion, data is being fetched correctly, list is being updated, but view is not (it stays like list before device lock was active).

**Code:**
Callback from backend with changed list:

```
 override fun onDataSetChanged(prepareList: List<Long>) {
    mPrepareAdapter.setOnDataSetChanged(prepareList)
}
```

Adapter:

```
var prepareList: MutableList<Long> = ArrayList()
...
fun setOnDataSetChanged(list: List<Long>){
    prepareList.clear()
    prepareList.addAll(list)
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    Log.d("prepareListAdapter", prepareList.toString())
}
```

**Note:** I did not post lifecycle methods like `onResume()` etc. as they work correctly. Having said that, they only are supposed to remove data observers or add them to observe database changes. As mentionted above, data is fetched correctly for whole the time, even after device is locked and unlocked, but just view is not being updated.
Plus, I've set layout manager in `onCreate()`, before adapter is set.

**Edit:** after reading this post couple of times and focusing on bolded word "only" next to "view", it lead me to debug this app on mobile device and create a second adapter using `FirebaseUI`. Here are some notes from my tests:

- Android TV has some kind of weird Activity Lifecycle, as it works properly on mobile devices
- It is not data/method related bug. It's  related to a view or a context.
- As mentioned in a point above, it's not a data delivery problem, so calling `NotifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()` doesn't fix the problem, because it's (?) view-related problem.

**Behaviour with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter on Android TV:**
Application works fine as long as device is not locked. After device is locked and unlocked RecyclerView is being cleared, even though logs show that data is still fetched properly and should be displayed.

So, it sounds to me like after device relock, adapter loses its view reference, here's my `onCreateViewHolder()` code, analogical is in Kotlin class:

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    if (inflater == null) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_textview_prepare, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Creating new instance of adapter in `onResume()` (yay, we shouldn't do that, I know), passing context to adapter? Nothing helps, RecyclerView still stays **blank**.

So, the only difference againist extending `RecyclerView.Adapter` and `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is that, in the prior one the old list is being displayed, when in the latter View reference is being lost (? isn't?).

For the end: here's the funny thing. This works properly not on all the mobile devices, even working on the same Android version. The bug occurs on both real Android TV and Android TV emulator (one with Google APIs).

I know it's a quite a long post and a lot to read, I'm sorry for that, but do you have any ideas what can I do more to fix it? I've been trying to fix that for the third day and nothing more comes up to my mind.

Comment: How about using firestore recycler view it'll automatically update views whenever new entries are added

Comment: @Mr.Patel I haven't tried it yet on this project, but I'd rather know where I could have done mystake in this code, as it may happen with local database too.

Comment: why did not you use onResume methode?

Comment: Please check my answer and still after this if problem is not solved i strongly suggest you to use firestore recycler view.

Comment: Any error logs?

Comment: @elbertrivas I've logged whole application and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onResume()` method, do a `notifyDataSetChanged()`, since you lock the device, when you come back to it, it should trigger `onResume()` and then, you can refresh your view.

[image]

Comment: Hey! I've just updated my main post. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem